# How to quickly convert two column CSV to a table/excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python

I have a two column CSV:

```
Name, Sport
Abraham Soccer
Adam Basketball
Adam Soccer
John Soccer
Jacob Tennis
Jacob Soccer
```

What is the simplest way to convert this into something openable in Excel that is either in XLS or CSV such that when opening up in MS Excel, it looks something like:

```
      Basketball, Soccer, Tennis
Abraham      X
Adam         X         X         X
John                   X     
Jacob                  X         X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) to be a suitable package for this kind of application. The centerpiece of `pandas` is a `dataframe` object (`df`), which is in essence a table of your data. csv files can be read into pandas using [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

In [3]:df
Out[3]: 
      Name       Sport
0  Abraham      Soccer
1     Adam  Basketball
2     Adam      Soccer
3     John      Soccer
4    Jacob      Tennis
5    Jacob      Soccer
```

There is a `pandas` method [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) that does what you want as simply as

```
table = pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['Sport'])

In [4]:table
Out[4]: 
Sport    Basketball  Soccer  Tennis
Name                               
Abraham           0       1       0
Adam              1       1       0
Jacob             0       1       1
John              0       1       0
```

Then you can convert back to a csv file with

```
table.to_csv('filename.csv')
```